# What's the optimal way to merge k lists?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

Suppose you're given a merge function that will merge (find the union of) two lists L1 and L2 of size s1 and s2 in O(s1+s2) time. What is the optimal way to merge k lists of size s1, s2, ..., sk?

I'm thinking that we should sort s1, ..., sk initially and sort the first two lists that correspond to the lowest two sizes. When these are merged, we find the position of their size in the sorted size list and continue the process until we end up with one list.

I'm having trouble with two things: 1. whether this is indeed optimal (is there another method that will return in faster time)? 2. how do we analyze the running time when the list size changes when we merge?

Answer (score 2):

This is *precisely* the same problem as finding the optimal variable-length bit-encoding for a string formed from an alphabet of `k` symbols with known frequencies `s1, s2, … sk`. Your algorithm is precisely the [Huffman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), and you'll find a proof of optimality in any textbook on algorithms (and many online resources) because it is the classic case of a greedy algorithm with a simple correctness proof.

The repeated application of a two-way merge induces a binary tree in which each node is a merge. Given that tree, the contribution of any leaf to the total cost of the overall merge is the weight of that leaf multiplied by its depth in the tree. (Each node is a merge, and the values in the leaf participate exactly in the merges in the path from the leaf to the root; the number of such merges is the depth of the leaf in the tree.) Similarly -- or identically --, the total length of a Huffman-encoded bitstring is the sum of the products of the weight (frequency) of symbol with the depth of the leaf corresponding to that symbol in the construction tree.

One small improvement to your algorithm (which is often missed by people writing Huffman tree builders): it is necessary to sort the weights `s1, s2, … sk`, but that's the only sort needed. From there, the algorithm always selects the two lowest nodes and adds them. The resulting sums must be monotonically non-decreasing in size (if a sum is smaller than a previous sum, the previous sum could not have been the sum of the two smallest elements). So you can put the sums in a queue; at each step you choose the two smallest elements from either the sorted array of leaves or the (implicitly) sorted queue of nodes.

This can be optimized further by overwriting the array of leaves with the queue of nodes. (The queue then grows from the bottom of the array towards the top; it's fairly simple to prove that the top of the queue will never overtake the bottom of the array.)

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you. Can you please just elaborate on why we only need to sort the weights once? Suppose the sorted list of weights is s1,s2,...,sk. Then the algorithm will merge lists corresponding to s1 and s2 to produce s12, and the "sorted" list will now look like s12, s3, ..., sk. But s12+s3 may be larger than s3+s4.

Comment: Or is it: if our sorted sizes are s1,s2,...,sk corresponding to lists L1,L2,...Lk, then we first merge L1 and L2 into L12, then L3 and L4 into L34 to get L12, L34, ..., Lk-1Lk and just continue this proess until we're left with one list? If so, what do we do when the number of lists is odd? For example, if we have L1, L2, L3, L4, L5 will the iterations look like: L12, L34, L5 -> L1234, L5 -> L12345?

Comment: @BobJonas: There are two lists: a list of leaves (which is constantly getting smaller) and a list of compounds (which is growing). Initially, the compounds are empty. We start with s1,s2,s3,s4;-. After the first step, we have `(s1,s2),s3,s4,...;s12`. (Deleted elements in parentheses.) If `s3` and `s4` are now the smallest (`s12>s4`), we then have `(s1,s2,s3,s4),s5,s6,...;s12,s34`. Otherwise `s3` and `s12` are the two smallest, and we would have `(s1,s2,s3),s4,s5,...;(s12),s123`. We also have to look at three elements to choose the smallest two: the smallest of each list, and...

Comment: ... the second smallest of the list whose first element is the smallest. The key is that the list of composites doesn't need to be sorted, because it is produced in sorted order, and the list of leaves is sorted once and remains sorted. In effect, we merge the two sorted lists, but one of the lists is generated lazily. At the end, both lists are empty, but if we move pointers rather than deleting, we have a sorted list of leaves and a sort list of compounds. If we use the same array, the compounds overwrite the deleted leaves.

Comment: OK, thank you! The only thing that honestly does not make sense to me is how we analyze the running time. Because if the leave can move around in the array, then how do we know which ones need to travel to the root or, for that matter, what the depth of any of them are?

Comment: @BobJonas: Hard question, unless we know something about s1,...,sk. An upper bound is O(N log k) where N is the sum of all the s1,...,sk, which is O(N log N) if all the s's are 1 and O(N) if k is 1. A tighter bound may be available for some distributions, but afaik only for pathological distributions (all the s's are 1 except for one, for example).